# Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xero/api/ApiClient

Tags: java, xero-api

I have got all the access token and secret from xero but when trying to access the xero api using `ApiClient`, getting error

> Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xero/api/ApiClient

I am trying this out using springboot java

```
ApiClient apiClientForAccounting = new 
ApiClient(config.getApiUrl(), null, null, null);

AccountingApi accountingApi = new AccountingApi(apiClientForAccounting);
accountingApi.setOAuthToken(xeroSettings.getActualOAuthToken(), xeroSettings.getActualOAuthTokenSecret());

Organisations organisations = accountingApi.getOrganisations();
```

Comment: What are the dependencies you are having. Please share build tree / dependencies.

Comment: for xero, i have the following dependency                                                                       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.xeroapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>xero-java</artifactId>
            <version>${xero.version}</version>
     <exclusions>
  <exclusion>
                   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
        </dependency>

Comment: <repository>
      <id>xero-accounting-api-schema-mvn-repo</id>
            <url>https://raw.github.com/XeroAPI/XeroAPI-Schemas/mvn-repo/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository><repository>
            <id>xero-java-mvn-repo</id>
            <url>https://raw.github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Java/mvn-repo/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots></repository>